# Which class does this class extends from?

Tags: scala

I wrote this line of code which appears to be wrong, but actually compiles:

```
class A extends {}
```

Which class does A extends from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A extends from java.lang.Object.
You can try the following code in the scala interpreter:

```
class A extends {}
val a = classOf[A].getSuperclass
```

The output is:

```
a: Class[_ >: A] = class java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually `extends {}` is always desugared into AnyRef construct, which is an alias for `java.lang.Object`. For example in structural typing you can write:

```
def test[A <: {def some: String}](a: A) = a
```

and here `{def some: String}` is a subtype of `AnyRef` with `some`:

```
test: [A <: AnyRef{def some: String}](a: A)A
```

Comment: amazing... scala grammar is so complicated (powerful too)